# Simulating Errors on the Amazon FPS sandbox

Tags: php, sandbox, frame-rate

I've set up my Amazon flexible payments sandbox account and have been using the PHP library to simulate accepting payments and what not.

I was just wondering if anyone knew of a way to simulate realistic error conditions I would expect to encounter, such as what happens when someone runs a card that gets declined.

The API guide does tell you what status codes will be returned, and something tells me I just have to trust them, but I always like to test as much as possible if possible.

Comment: OK, well further review of the documentation revealed the error testing you can do so I figured I would put it up here if anyone else was wondering:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonFPS/latest/FPSAccountManagementGuide/CHAP_Sandbox.html

Comment: Thats indeed the correct solution.

Comment: It's a nice idea, shame it's so limited. There's a lot of scenarios with other services I'd like to simulate too such as with subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

A link to the answer is in the comments here, but it wouldn't hurt to have an actual answer with a summary.  There's details about simulating error conditions in the testing sandbox in the [advanced quick start guide](https://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/FPS_ASP_Guides/FPS_Advanced_Quick_Start.pdf).

The following errors can be simulated by setting the value for **SenderTokenId**:

> Closed account:    *Z1LGRXR4HMDZBSFKXELA32KZASGWD8IHMHZCK4DETR784LDLD1GMFW4P3WT8VTGX*
>
> Email address not verified:    *E3FR7BARJV3PB631PMKV74PGKCJLBHI1Q1KMQN7BJ2JJICPDKN3N1CJIKFZ8D7NN*
>
> Suspended account:    *H216UECZ8ZM1G8G4QA3V7RKF8JDFZ9SI3SJAFSGUKBBNDHX1NVM8GUQRZNRNAHER*

The following errors can be simulated by setting the value for **RecipientTokenId**:

> Closed account:    *P1LL7A1LHK935DBGI5NAYCXOCLVEBHBNIU7PBXBAMRKKNLDEPI8M3MUSLZT2VANZ*
>
> Email address not verified:    *C4LGSEMXN11FTUXZ2X2C7QVFHN5DVBGQJNF17AIQXXXQSX4DRG4KJFCN2KRFUUZI*
>
> Suspended account:    *R3VK49XVGCAZTJSXKN7ZSBHPMFGKM5VEEQTXGMVE8CFUZ2G5RLLMAB4J6TQRL6BU*

And finally, setting the **amount** value such that it includes a decimal value between the following values will simulate the following errors:

> Temporary Decline:    *.60 to .69*
>
> Payment Error:    *.70 to .89*

Unfortunately, that last detail may be out of date.  [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/2008-09-17/FPSAdvancedGuide/index.html?CHAP_Sandbox.html) page seems to imply that having 7 or 8 after the decimal point will create the terribly generic "Failure".  From testing, I can confirm that 0.6 does lead to a temporary failure (status is stuck in "Pending" for a while before eventually advancing to "Success"), and 0.7 and 0.8 result in the same "TransactionDenied" error.